# Debuggin nasm with gdb -- external subroutine file not found

Tags: gdb, nasm

I have two source files:

- main3.asm
- prt_dec.asm

I compile and link the files with the following commands:

```
nasm -f elf -g -F stabs main3.asm
nasm -f elf -g -F stabs prt_dec.asm
ld -m elf_i386 main3.o prt_dec.o
```

I run gdb with the following command:

```
gdb ./a.out
```

All is well. There are no compilation or linking errors and the program returns the desired results. However, I would like to step through the program with gdb to better understand the internals and the debugging tool itself. The problem I run into is this:

Although gdb calls the externally defined subroutine prt_dec, it doesn't appear to have access to the source code in which it was defined. For example, if use the following command in gdb:

```
(gdb) list main3.asm:1
```

I get the first 10 lines of the main3.asm source code file. However, when I try to use the same command on the other source code file:

```
(gdb) list prt_dec.asm:1
```

I get the error **"No source file named prt_dec.asm"**

What's going on here?  Why can't gdb see the source code for the other file that was linked?

---

If it helps, I've include the source code files below (both files have been shortened and irrelevant code removed):

main3.nasm:

```
        SECTION .data                   ; initialized data section

lf:     db  10                          ; just a linefeed 

        SECTION .text                   ; Code section.

        global  _start                  ; let loader see entry point
        extern  prt_dec

_start:
        push    dword 42
        call    prt_dec
        add     esp, 4

        mov     eax, 4                  ; write message
        mov     ebx, 1
        mov     ecx, lf
        mov     edx, 1                  ; LF is a single character
        int     080h

exit:   mov     eax, 1                  ; exit function
        mov     ebx, 0                  ; exit code, 0=normal
        int     080h                    ; ask kernel to take over
```

---

prt_dec.asm:

```
[section .data]

digits: db "0123456789"         ; decimal digits lookup table


[section .bss]

outputBuffer:   resb 10         ; largest 32-bit value represented in decimal
                                ; is 10 digits (2^32)


[section .txt]

global prt_dec

prt_dec:

; code here takes 32-bit value on stack when
; subroutine was called, converts and stores the decimal
; representation of the 32-bit value in outputBuffer,
; and writes the result to stdout

ret
```

Comment: Change `[section .txt]` to `[section .text]`.

Comment: Wow!  What a simple mistake!  Thank you!!!